# How to Instantiate Child Class from Instatiated Parent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, extends

I'm writing a node.js app and I get a net.Socket from a net.Server. I'm writing a class called RpcSocket:

```
class RpcSocket {
constructor(socket) {
    this.idToAssign = 1;

    this.handlers = {};

    this.socket = socket;

    this.socket.on('error', e => log.error('socket', e));

    const incoming = JSONStream.parse();

    incoming.on('data', object => {
        const parsedObject = jsonrpc.parseObject(object);

        switch (parsedObject.type) {
            case 'request':
                const response = this.handlers[parsedObject.payload.method](parsedObject.payload.id); // TODO check if it exists
                socket.write(JSON.stringify(response));
                break;
            case 'success':
                console.log('success', parsedObject.payload.result); // TODO do something useful, use the ID. Probably need to track IDs
        }
    });

    incoming.on('error', e => log.error('incoming', e));

    socket.pipe(incoming);
}

setHandler(method, func) {
    this.handlers[method] = func;
}

request(method, params) {
    this.socket.write(JSON.stringify(jsonrpc.request(this.idToAssign++, method, params)));
}}
```

Currently this class simply takes a socket and assigns it as an instance property. I would like for RpcSocket to extend Socket. The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to turn an instantiated Socket into an RpcSocket.

Comment: let myrpcSocket = new RpcSocket(new net.Socket(options )) ?

Comment: @infamoustrey the Socket returned from "new net.Socket(options)" wouldn't be connected. This project will use peer-to-peer TCP communication so I don't have a server to connect to. Currently I listen using a net.Server then when my peer connects (I always start up before them) I'm returned a socket to use.

Comment: Sounds like your child class just needs to have some methods for connecting

Comment: @ndeselms Then just wrap that socket you got to use with your `new PpcSocket` constructor?

Comment: "*I can't figure out how to turn an instantiated Socket into an RpcSocket.*" - you can't (without dark magic), and you shouldn't. Using a wrapper is fine. There's no reason to use subclassing here.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I ended up writing the class as `RpcConnection` which has a `socket` property so more or less a wrapper.